# How to replace console output when the string gets shorter?

Tags: python, linux

I know that i can replace console output instead of adding a new line with "\r"
But how to do that with an output that can get smaller as it started?
I googled and only found how to do it with a progressbar.

Comment: Print out some spaces over the top of the bit you want to erase

Comment: Use `tput el` to get the specific string to clear to the end of line for your terminal, but very likely you can use `\r\x1b\x5b\x4b`

Comment: Another way to write that is `\r\e[K`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import time

def disappearingPrint(message, interval):
  for i in range(0, len(message)):
    print(message[:len(message)-i]+" "*i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(interval)

disappearingPrint("Hello world", 1)
```

I'm adding spaces every time one character is removed